# Что будет находиться в ch2 после выполнения след. кода?

Tags: javascript

```js
var ch1 = 'b';
var ch2;
switch (ch1) {
  case 'a':
    ch2 = '1';
  case 'b':
    ch2 = '2';
  case 'c':
    ch2 = '3';
    break;
  default:
    ch2 = '4';

}
```

Варианты ответов:

1
2
3
4
null

Comment: Ну, просто выполните этот код и посмотрите что получится?

Comment: А запустить и посмотреть не пробовали?

Comment: @Sergej Kalva запустить я пробовал, меня интересовало аргументированное объяснение процесса, а не тупо минусование вопроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как оператор break находится только в 3 кейсе (case 'c'), то в переменной ch2 будет находиться строка '3'.